# Элемент не получает фокус

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть скрипт, который при клике на кнопку добавляет на страницу ul c li. Когда фокус находится на li и пользователь нажимает Enter - я создаю еще 1 li и вставляю после первого. После чего делаю на последнем фокус. Например:

```
let activeLi;//активная li
let newLi = $('<li></li>');
activeLi.after(newLi);
newLi.focus();
```

Html имеет такой вид

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    <ul>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Но фокус не ставится на новый элемент, а остается на старом. В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: `activeLi.afetr(newLi);`  не `afetr` а `after`

Comment: Ваши ошибка в том, что вы не смотрите консоль, в которой написана ошибка.

Comment: @UbuntuUser, опечатка

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, ошибок в консоли нету

Comment: а что консоль показывает после `activeLi.after(newLi);` - `console.log(newLi);`

Comment: Извините, а разве **li** поддерживает `focus`?

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич http://joxi.ru/nAyK35VIYqZ8Pm

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, я думал что если она в div с contenteditable или ей указать такое свойство - тогда да. но я не уверен

Comment: Тут еще и `contenteditable`... В общем, приводите полный пример, как это у вас не работает. Потому что слишком много неизвестных переменных получается.

Comment: добавил html, может так понятнее будет

Answer (score 0):

Не забывай про `tabindex` и всё будет работать:

```js
$("li").focus().parent().keypress(function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    var li = $("<li tabindex=0>")
    $(e.target).after(li)
    li.focus()
  }
})
```

```css
ul { counter-reset: i }
li { counter-increment: i }
li:after { content: counter(i) }
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li tabindex=0>
</ul>
```

Comment: немного не те. у меня contenteditable. то есть, у меня не просто фокус, а курсор стоит. и мне надо что бы курсор становился в новый созданный li

Comment: @Diefair, тогда используй не focus, а selection api, только jquery идёт лесом.

Comment: можно и на обычном js. можете подсказать как это сделать с помощью selection api?